# Best fitting and tangent sphere inside an ellipsoid (spheroid) at a given geodetic latitude

Tags: geometry, analysis, spherical-trigonometry

I don't know if there is a name of such a thing, but I would be thankful for each help.

I have an ellispoid (exactly it's an oblate ellipsoid) with with equatorial radius $a$ and a polar radius $b$.

At a given (geodetic) Latitude $φ$ is there a point $P$ at the surface of this ellipsoid , I would to draw a sphere inside the ellipsoid fitting and it's tangent at $P$ .

Which radius $R$  should it have?
And where should the coordinates of its center $A (x, y, z)$ be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean "the largest sphere tangent a $P$ and contained inside the spheroid"?

Comment: @Aretino, yes that is what I mean, the sphere would be an approach of the surface at $P$

Comment: And with this sphere, I can approximate the distance to the horizon in all direrctions, when standing at height $h$ and perpendicular to $P$

Comment: If you want the sphere best approximating the spheroid surface then you need the osculating sphere, which is not the one mentioned above.

Comment: Is this "osculating sphere" local, right? So only for my wished location at a given Latitude

Comment: Yes, of course. Its radius is the local radius of curvature of the spheroid.

Comment: Ok, then that is what I search for... could you me help or consulting websites for formulae?

Comment: Specially, the coordinates of the center of this sphere... radius is easy to calculate , isnt?

Comment: Unfortunately, different sections of the spheroid have different curvatures, so what you ask is impossible.

Comment: The distance to the horizon will depend on the direction you are looking at, won't it? For example think of the person standing on the equator of an ellipsoid with $b$ much less than $a$. They cannot see very far towards either pole, but along the equator the distance to the horizon only depends on $a$. This is just another way of saying what Aretino said above.